# recurrence relation with induction

Tags: recurrence-relations, induction

The following recurrence relation:
$T(n)=T(n-1)+n=1+\frac{n^2+n}{2}=\theta(n^2)$, so this mean that:
there is $c_1, c_2, n_o > 0 : c_1n^2<=1+\frac{n^2+n}{2}<=c_2n^2$,
the second inequality it's easy, but how to prove by induction the first:
$c_1n^2<=1+\frac{n^2+n}{2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $c_1=1/2$, then you can directly see that

$$c_1n^2\le 1+\frac{n^2+n}{2}$$

If you want to use induction, you get with $c_1=1/2$

$$\frac{(n+1)^2}{2}\le 1+\frac{(n+1)^2}{2}+\frac{(n+1)}{2}$$

This is equivalent to

$$0\le 1+\frac{(n+1)}{2}$$
which is obviously satisfied for all $n\ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this exactly:
$$
\begin{align*}
T(n) - T(n - 1)
  &= \frac{n^2 - n + 2}{2} \\
\sum_{1 \le n \le m} (T(n) - T(n - 1)) 
  &= \frac{1}{2} \left( \sum_{1 \le n \le m} n^2
                          - \sum_{1 \le n \le m} n + 2 m \right) \\
T(m)
  &= T(0) + \frac{m^3 - m + 6}{6}
\end{align*}
$$